# HDD boot repair

Tags: 14.04, dell, bootloader, boot-repair

I just used `boot-repair` tool in Ubuntu and I applied MBR option …
and when I reboot my laptop, it won't boot hard drive. A black screen appears with a cursor beeping and my whole system stucks there …

Please help …  my laptop is *Dell Latitude D520*

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Grub2 installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

and look for the `Reinstalling GRUB 2` section. Then check the `Fixing a Broken System` section .. you will have to use a LiveCD.  This should solve your problems

Comment: If not grub, may be video? What video card/chip? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: this doesn't sound like video .. grubs basic video will usually work ... the video driver issues come later in the boot process .. I feel its more grub because they can't even show any try to boot .. just black screen with flashing cursor .. usually a sign of no 'boot' information

Comment: If only Ubuntu, not dual boot, you never see grub and it just starts to boot. So need to know system configuration to really know.

Comment: lol true i suppose .. i forget that a lot of people dont mess with their settings .. lol first thing i do is enable the boot menu :D but still usually a video driver issue would manifest itself a bit later .. you would usually see some sort of output